# how to get top and bottom coordinates of all the patches of a specific gray value in an image using python opencv?

Tags: python, opencv

I have a gray level image. It contains patches in different gray values.

There could be distinct patches at different locations in the image having the same gray value.

I want to get the upper and lower coordinates of all the patches of a specific gray value.

By upper I mean the highest value of the y coordinate of that patch regardless of x coordinate.

By lower I mean the lowest value of the y coordinate of that patch regardless of x coordinate.

I need such (x,y) pairs for all the patches of a specific gray level.

Thanks

Comment: Post a "test image". It might help people try out their code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used the Python version of OpenCV, but basically, what you want to do is (in C++ syntax):

```
cv::Mat labels = image == gray_value;
```

This will create a BW image where all the patches with gray value == `gray_value` having a value of 255 and the rest is set to 0;

```
vector<vector<Point> > contours;
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
findContours( labels, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
```

This will find the contour surrounding each patch.

Finally, you need to loop through the contours and find `y_min` and `y_max` for each of them (since I think the contours are external to the actual patches, I think you'll need to subtract one from max and add one to min, but I am not sure about that)